# How to modify code in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel and then refer to it from elsewhere?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'd like to (try to) add HTTP/2 support to Kestrel - for my own edification, for now. I'm using Ubuntu as my dev platform, because my requirements include using Linux.

Of course, it appears fairly simple to make changes to the Kestrel code - just clone the source from https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer, then make my changes, then build the assembly. The problem I'm having, is getting other code to reference my modified code/assembly rather than the "official" assembly from .NET Core. To that end, I would love to hear how to do the following:

- "Install" my changed Kestrel assembly locally such that anything that depends on that assembly uses my changes automatically. This may include projects that I create via **dotnet new -t web**, as well as other .NET Core assemblies that I haven't modified.
- Be able to propagate my changes to other machines as necessary, in a controlled manner.

Thank you, and have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options

- create own nuget package from sources using [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-pack) command, and then use own feed for nuget restore. See related [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37867569/2833802) and [Hosting your own nuget feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) guide;
  or
- add Kestrel project into your solution and add dependency as "project reference".